# How could I ping my docker container from my host

Tags: macos, docker, networking

I have created a ubuntu docker container on my mac

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND      CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                 NAMES
5d993a622d23  ubuntu  "/bin/bash"  42 minutes ago  Up 42 minutes  0.0.0.0:123->123/tcp  kickass_ptolemy
```

I set port as 123.

My container IP is `172.17.0.2`

```
docker inspect 5d993a622d23 | grep IP
"LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

On my Mac I try to ping my container,

`Ping 172.17.0.2`, I got Request timeout for icmp_seq 0....

What should I do? So my local machine can ping the container I installed. Did I missing some app installation on my container, which is a plain ubuntu system?

Comment: Docker for Mac or Docker Toolbox?

Comment: You should mention what version of Ubuntu you are using and what version of Docker you are using. Also, have you checked out the Docker documentation on networking that applies to your Docker version?

Comment: Docker for Mac, Docker 1.12.1, Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[You can't ping or access a container interface directly with Docker for Mac](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22753#issuecomment-222943352).

> The current best solution is to connect to your containers from
> another container. At present there is no way we can provide routing
> to these containers due to issues with OSX that Apple have not yet
> resolved. we are tracking this requirement, but we cannot do anything
> about it at present.

### lima

[Lima](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima) can add host accessible interfaces on a VM via [`socket_vmnet`](https://lima-vm.io/docs/config/network/#socket_vmnet)  (It's 2023 now, lima is used in rancher/podman desktop)

```bash
# Install
brew install lima socket_vmnet

# Customise the `shared` network if required. 
vi ~/.lima/_config/networks.yaml

# Set up the sudoers file for launching `socket_vmnet` from Lima
limactl sudoers >etc_sudoers.d_lima
sudo install -o root etc_sudoers.d_lima /etc/sudoers.d/lima

# Create a containerd VM on the `shared` network
echo | limactl start \
  --network lima:shared \
  --vm-type vz \
  --mount-type virtiofs \
  --set '.containerd.system = true | .containerd.user = false' \
  template://debian-12

# You may want to add this ip/mac address to /etc/bootptab
# so the IP address remains consistent on this VM. 
lima ip -j address show lima0 \
 | jq -r '.[0] as $if
    | "lima  1  \($if.address)  \($if.addr_info[] |select(.family == "inet") |.local)"'

# Setup network and route
lima sudo nerdctl network create ctr01 --subnet 10.2.3.0/24
sudo /sbin/route add 10.2.3.0/24 192.168.105.3 # or configured networks.yaml

# Test
lima sudo nerdctl run --detach --net ctr01 --ip 10.2.3.3 nginx
ping -c 2 10.2.3.3
curl http://10.2.3.3
```

### Docker Toolbox/VirtualBox

When running Docker Toolbox, Docker Machine via VirtualBox or any VirtualBox VM (like [a Vagrant definition](https://github.com/deployable/docker-debianvm)) you can setup a ["Host-Only Network"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) and access the Docker VMs network via that.

If you are using the `default` boot2docker VM, don't change the existing interface as you will stop a whole lot of Docker utilities from working, add a new interface.

You will also need to setup routing from your Mac to the container networks via your VM's new IP address. In my case the Docker network range is `172.22.0.0/16` and the Host Only adapter IP on the VM is `192.168.99.100`.

```
sudo route add 172.22.0.0/16 192.168.99.100
```

Adding a [permanent route to osx](http://www.poserio.com/how-to-add-persistent-static-routes-on-osx-yosemite/) is bit more complex

Then you can get to containers from your Mac

```
machost:~ ping -c 1 172.22.0.2
PING 172.22.0.2 (172.22.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.364 ms

--- 172.22.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.364/0.364/0.364/0.000 ms
```

#### Vagrant + Ansible setup

Here's my running config...

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/contrib-buster64"
  config.vm.hostname = "docker"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.7.7.7", hostname: true
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = "4000"
    vb.cpus = "4"
  end
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.playbook = "tasks.yaml"
  end
end
```

The ansible `tasks.yaml` to configure a fixed network.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: auto_silent
    docker_config:
      bip: 10.7.2.1/23
      host: ["tcp://10.7.7.7:2375"]
      userland-proxy: false
  tasks:

  - ansible.builtin.apt:
      update_cache: yes
      force_apt_get: yes
      pkg:
      - bridge-utils
      - docker.io
      - python3-docker
      - python-docker
      - iptables-persistent

  - ansible.builtin.hostname:
      name: docker

  - ansible.builtin.copy:
      content: "{{ docker_config | to_json }}"
      dest: /etc/docker/daemon.json

  - ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      line: 'DOCKER_OPTS="{% for host in docker_config.host %} -H {{ host }} {% endfor %}"'
      regexp: '^DOCKER_OPTS='
      path: /etc/default/docker

  - ansible.builtin.systemd:
      name: docker.service
      state: restarted
  
  - ansible.builtin.iptables:
      action: insert
      chain: DOCKER-USER
      destination: 10.7.2.0/23
      in_interface: eth1
      out_interface: docker0
      jump: ACCEPT
  - ansible.builtin.shell: iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Add the route for the docker bridge network via the VM to the mac

```
$ sudo /sbin/route -n -v add -net 10.7.2.0/23 10.7.7.7
```

Then set `DOCKER_HOST=10.7.7.7` in the environment to use the new VM.

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=10.7.7.7 
$ docker run --name route_test --rm -d node:14-slim node -e "require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'})
 res.end('hello')
}).listen(3000)"
$ docker container inspect route_test -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress }}'
$ curl http://10.7.2.3:3000
hello
$ docker rm -f route_test
```

You don't get volumes mapped from the host to the vm, but as a bonus it uses a lot less cpu than the Docker 2.5.x release.

Comment: How do I find the Docker network range 172.22.0.0/16 on my machine? How do I find the Host Only adapter IP on the VM 192.168.99.100 on my machine? In the question asked he used 172.17.0.2, whats the relation? Broken links...

Comment: @powder366 The Docker network range is on the VM. Either in the Docker for Mac moby VM or whatever other VM platform you are running. An `ip ad sh` on a VM terminal will list the IP's.

Comment: Is this statement still true "You can't ping or access a container interface directly with Docker for Mac"? If not, how can I get the external IP of my docker container (I'm using `docker compose`)

Comment: @BonisTech This was a limitation of the the mac hypervisor framework that docker used, which I believe is still the case. The work around is to add a tunnel device to the mac and vm, like a wireguard connection, to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, if your container has a bash shell incorporated,  you can access it through

`docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash`

and then you can ping your virtual ip

Answer (score 5):

It works in this scenario:

1. Windows host
2. Linux VM installed on Windows host
3. Docker container installed on Linux VM host

Now you have to note this. Containers are in a isolated network but connected to the internet throught your Docker container host adapter.So you have to tell kernel linux to be available in your network then in your Linux VM:

```sh
# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
# sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Now in you Windows host you have to add a route for our container network:
route add "Docker container network" "Linux VM IP" for example

```sh
# route add 172.17.0.0/16 192.168.1.20
```

Comment: This is exactly my setup and this answer worked for me. The key change in iptables was `(policy DROP)` to `(policy ACCEPT)` in the FORWARD chain.

Comment: "Now in you Windows host you have to add a route ..." -> Where should this route add go to?

Answer (score 0):

setup:

`PC-A` a is docker host, `PC-B` is a another PC in the network. To ping/access docker's container from `PC-B`, run the below `iptables`-rules in the host.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

note: `eth0` is host's interface and `docker0` is docker's virtual default bridge.

Now add route in `PC-B`

```
route add -net <dockerip> netmask <net mask> gw <docker's host>
```

ping/access container services directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have W-> windows machine, L-Linux Vbox VM (eth0,eth1) and docker app (using port 8989) running on this L-Linux Vbox VM. Provider does not have to Vbox anyway or W-> a win.You want to type http://app:8989 on your browser.There are two methods afak; easy way to run vagrant automatically or manually configure Vbox VM with port forwarding through "Host-only Adapter" which is actually eth1; normally eth0 is Vbox's default reserved 10.0.2.15 IP assignment.Or on command prompt on win/lin/mac through "VBoxManage" command you can set up networks or automate through scripts.

```
webtier.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8989, host: 8989
```

run docker app

```
sudo docker run -p 8989:8989 ...
```

on windows explorer(W-> windows machine) browse your app

```
http://app:8989
```

You still can not ping "172.17.0.2" which is docker container IP in this situation from W-> windows machine.This could run cross-platform win/lin/mac.You might want to look into Vbox Manual and Vagrant Manual,  particularly networks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run the containers of interest in one and the same network with an additional container with OpenVPN server, so that you can see containers over VPN connection from the host:

- Use `docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/24 my-net` to [create a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) where containers will see each other.
- Attach containers to it using `--net my-net` parameter for `docker run`.
- Run an additional container with [OpenVPN](https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn/) in the same network. This time you need a port mapping for VPN connection `-p 1194:1194/udp`.
- Use OpenVPN client on the host to connect to this network with containers to ping them.

Also, you may need to comment out `redirect-gateway` instruction in OpenVPN client config file and add `push "route 172.19.0.0 255.255.255.0"` to (and remove other pushes from) the server config file.