# Vagrant to Docker communication via Docker IP address

Tags: django, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

Here's my situation. We are slowly migrating our VMs from Vagrant to Docker but we are mostly still Docker newbs. Some of our newer system's development environments have already been moved to Docker. We have test code that runs on an older Vagrant VM and used to communicate with a Vagrant running a Django Restful API application in order to run integration tests. This Django API is now in a Docker container. So now we need the test code that runs in a vagrant to be able to make requests to the API running in docker. Both the docker container and the vagrant are running side by side on a host machine (MacOS). We are using Docker compose to initialize the docker container the main compose yaml file is shown below.

```
services:
  django-api:
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.bapi
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yml
      service: django-api
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ../:/workspace
    command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
    env_file:
      - ${HOME}/.pam_environment
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGPORT=5432
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=password
      - CLOUDAMQP_URL=amqp://rabbitmq

  db:
    ports:
      - "5432"
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yml
      service: db
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-postgress-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-postgress-db.sh
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: django-api-dev
```

I would like the tests that are running on the vagrant to still be able to communicate with the django application that's now running on docker, similar to the way it could communicate with the api when it was running in a vagrant. I have tried several different types of network configurations within the docker compose file but alas networking is not my strong suit and I'm really just shooting in the dark here.

Is there a way to configure my docker container and/or my vagrant so that they can talk to each other? I need to expose my docker container's IP address so that my vagrant can access it.

Any help/tips/guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vagrantfile, make sure you have a private host only network. I usually use them with a fixed IP

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.100"
```

Now both the VMs will get a static IP in the host only network. When you run `docker-compose up -d` in your Django VM. Your VM will map port `8080` to the container `8080`. So you can use `192.168.33.100:8080` in the other VM for testing the APIs

Comment: So my vagrant setup uses a private host network `192.168.33.11`. Since I'm using VirtualBox I have an additional network adapter `vboxnet1`.

How does that machine communicate with the app running in a docker container. So next steps? Change my docker compose file and add a `networks` section?

Then create the network, e.g.?

    `docker network  create
        --subnet=192.168.33.0/24
        --gateway=192.168.33.1
        -o parent=vboxnet1 vboxnetdocker`

This doesn't work as written but just looking for steps on the docker end after vagrant is set up with a private network.

Comment: You can ping the VM from machine using `192.168.33.11`? If yes then you just need to map port while running the docker container `docker run -p 8080:8080 image`. From you machine 192.168.33.11:8080 would be accessible

Comment: Yes from the running docker container I can ping the vagrant VM, but I cannot ping the docker container given its IP address obtained by running `ifconfig` while on the docker. In other words I can communicate with the outside network but the outside cannot communicate to the container. Neither from my host machine nor the vagrant.

Maybe I wasn't clear, the docker container is not running ON the vagrant. They are running side by side. That's why I assume there is some extra networking work to be done on the docker side to allow the vagrant to send requests to the docker.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The host machine is MacOS docker and vagrant are both running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I just found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216830/how-could-i-ping-my-docker-container-from-my-host. I am also using docker for mac. It appears there may be limitations to having OSx as the host machine. The trick may be to not use docker for mac and try to run the docker via VirtualBox. I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: I do that only. Run a VM through vagrant and install docker over it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151572/discussion-between-rob-carpenter-and-tarun-lalwani).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the tests that are running on the vagrant to still be
>   able to communicate with the django application that's now running on
>   docker, similar to the way it could communicate with the api when it
>   was running in a vagrant.

As you say, you are using docker-compose, so exposing ports would do the purpose you are looking for. In the yml file, where django application is defined, create a port mapping which would bind the port on host to the port in container. You can do this by including this:

```
ports:
  "<host_port_where_you_want_to_access>:<container_port_where_application_is_running>"
```

> Is there a way to configure my docker container and/or my vagrant so
>   that they can talk to each other? I need to expose my docker
>   container's IP address so that my vagrant can access it.

It is. If both the containers are in the same network (when services are declared in same compose file, all services are in same network by default), then one container can talk to other container by calling to their service name.

**Example**: In the yml file specified in question, `django-api` can access `db` at `http://db:xxxx/` where xxxx can be any port inside container. `xxxx` need not be mapped to host or need not be exposed.