# Connect to Redis Docker container from Vagrant machine

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, vagrant

We're making move to Docker from Vagrant.

Our first aim is to move some services out first.  In this case I'm trying to host a redis server on a docker container and connect to it from my vagrant machine.

On the vagrant machine there is an apache2 webserver hosting a Laravel App

It's the connection part I'm struggling with, currently I have

**Dockerfile.redis**

```
FROM redis:3.2.12

RUN redis-server
```

**docker-compose.yml (concatenated)**

```
version: '3'
services:
   redis:
     build:
       context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.redis
       working_dir: /opt
       ports:
         - "6379:6379"
```

I've tried various way to connect to this:

**Attempt 1**

Using the host ip `10.0.2.2` in the config in Laravel. Results in a "Connection refused"

**Attempt 2**

Set up a network in the docker compose

```
redis:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.redis
  working_dir: /opt
  network:
    - app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
  ipam:
    driver: default
      - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

This instead results in timeouts.  Most solutions seem to require a gateway configured on the network, but this isn't configurable in docker compose 3.  Is there maybe a way around this?

If anyone can give any guidance that would be great, most guides talk about connect to dockers in a vagrant rather than from one.

FYI - this is using Docker for Mac and version 3 of docker compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to get this going use purely docker compose and not having a dockerfile for redis at all:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: redis
  working_dir: /opt
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

Once done like this, able to connect to redis from within the vagrant file using

```
redis-cli -h 10.0.2.2
```

Or as the following in laravel, although we're using environment variables to set these)

```
'redis' => [
  'client' => 'phpredis',
  'default' => [
    'host'     => '10.0.2.2',
    'password' => null,
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **Attempt 1** should work actually. When you create a service without defining a network, docker-compose automatically creates a bridge network. For example:

When you run `docker-compose up` on this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.redis
    working_dir: /opt
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

`docker-compose` creates a bridge network named `<project name>_default`, which is `docker_compose_test_default` in my case, as shown below:

```
me@myshell:~/docker_compose_test $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                          DRIVER              SCOPE
6748b1ea4b85        bridge                        bridge              local
4601c6ea30c3        docker_compose_test_default   bridge              local
80033acaa6e4        host                          host                local
```

When you inspect your container, you can see that an IP has already been assigned to it:

```
docker inspect e6b196f952af
...
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                ...
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
```

You can then use this IP to connect from the host or your vagrant box:

```
me@myshell:~/docker_compose_test $ redis-cli -h 172.18.0.2 -p 6379
172.18.0.2:6379> ping
PONG
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately this just resolves in a `Connection Timeout` from either my host or vagrant, could this be an issue with my redis rather than docker?

Comment: Does the docker logs from the container show that redis is running and listening on the required port?

Comment: Does in the terminal window, I assume this shows the same details as the logs

Comment: You could be running into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216830/how-could-i-ping-my-docker-container-from-my-host

Comment: The joys of your CTO returning and fixing this in 5mins haha.  Got this working I'll post the solution below