# Cannot ping docker container created with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create a PostgreSQL cluster composed by a master and two slaves within three containers. I want to do that with docker-compose. Everything works fine but I cannot ping containers from my Mac.

Here the code of my docker-compose.yml.

On Stackoverflow there is this thread [How could I ping my docker container from my host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216830/how-could-i-ping-my-docker-container-from-my-host) that address docker standalone and not docker-compose.

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
    pgmaster_volume:
    pgslave1_volume:
    pgslave2_volume:

services:
    pgmaster:
        container_name: pgmaster

        build:
            context: ../src
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

        image: docker-postgresql:latest

        environment:
            NODE_NAME: pgmaster # Node name

        ports:
            - 5422:5432

        volumes:
            - pgmaster_volume:/home/postgres/data

        networks:
            cluster:
                ipv4_address: 10.0.2.31
                aliases:
                    - pgmaster.domain.com

    pgslave1:
        container_name: pgslave1

        build:
            context: ../src
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

        image: docker-postgresql:latest

        environment:
            NODE_NAME: pgslave1 # Node name

        ports:
            - 5441:5432

        volumes:
            - pgslave1_volume:/home/postgres/data

        networks:
            cluster:
                ipv4_address: 10.0.2.32
                aliases:
                    - pgslave1.domain.com
    pgslave2:
        container_name: pgslave2

        build:
            context: ../src
            dockerfile: Dockerfile

        image: docker-postgresql:latest

        environment:
            NODE_NAME: pgslave2 # Node name

        ports:
            - 5442:5432

        volumes:
            - pgslave2_volume:/home/postgres/data

        networks:
            cluster:
                ipv4_address: 10.0.2.33
                aliases:
                    - pgslave2.domain.com

networks:
  cluster:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.2.1/24
```

On my Mac, I have a 192.168.0.0 local network. I expect that doing ping 10.0.2.31 I can ping my container but this is not possible. I think this is due to Linux VM created inside Mac where containers live and the IPs are not reachable outside this VM.

Can someone help me to understand how to make the above three IP reachable? IPs are reachable from one container to another.

Here my full code:
https://github.com/sasadangelo/docker-postgres

Comment: Hi, although I cannot explain indepth the technicalities of the issue, I can tell you that it works as it should and you shouldn't reach the containers that way. They are meant to work in isolation and be reached only on the ports that are exposed on the host. If you want to have access to the containers that way you can always create a host network and then you can ping the containers from anywhere on your network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I ping my docker container from my host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216830/how-could-i-ping-my-docker-container-from-my-host)

Comment: The short answer is typically "never think about the container-private IP addresses at all".  In your Docker Compose file I'd remove all of the `networks:` blocks, for example.  However you configure the containers to talk to each other they can use the block names like `pgmaster` as host names.

Comment: David Maze, it is not duplicated because I am talking about docker-compose and not docker standalone.

In an old version of my code, I didn't use docker-compose but simply docker. I had a script to define my network and my containers: https://github.com/sasadangelo/docker-postgres/blob/0.0.4/build_containers.sh and with this definition, I was able to ping my containers.

Comment: The documentation says that this is a limitation of Docker Desktop on macOS. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to `ping` your containers from you host.

- **via public ip**:

  just use their *public* ip. (you had been trying to ping your 
  container *local* ip, inside the docker network)

  how to find the container public IP?

  - you can get it by running `ifconfig` inside the container.

  *or*

  - or by running on your host `docker container inspect <container_id>`.

    it should be there under `NetworkSettings.<network_name>.IPAddress` )
- **via container name/id**

  docker is running some sort of dns on your machine so you can also use 
  the container name or id - `ping <container_name/id>`

**note**

the way to *access* your containers outside the docker network is via their published ports. you have bound port `5432` on the docker network to port `5442` on your host, therefore the container should listen and accept traffic at `127.0.0.1:5442` (thats your localhost at the port you've bound)

Comment: In an old version of my code, I didn't use docker-compose but simply docker. I had a script to define my network and my containers: https://github.com/sasadangelo/docker-postgres/blob/0.0.4/build_containers.sh and with this definition, I was able to ping my containers.

I don't understand why it worked using only docker instead of docker-compose.

Comment: Here the output of ifconfig inside the container:eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0a:00:02:1f  
          inet addr:10.0.2.31  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5136 (5.1 KB)  TX bytes:10442 (10.4 KB)

Comment: docker-compose is creating a private subnet for its services, when `docker run` throws the container in the default docker network. thats why its different. if you cant get the publich ip via ifconfig - go for the seond way. run `docker container inspect <container_id> ` to get the `NetworkSettings.<network_name>.IPAddress`, or simply ping the container name

Comment: I did it. ```docker container inspect <container_id>``` in ```NetworkSettings.<network_name>.IPAddress``` I got the 10.0.2.31 IP that I cannot ping.

Comment: I understand my issue. In my old code (without docker-compose) I use ssh to access to 10.0.2.31 from my Mac but I had defined an entry in .ssh/config where that IP is solved with localhost and a given port mapped on 22. So I didn't access to a real IP but simply to localhost. I completely forgot this configuration and I thought my old code was able to ping that IP. Instead as you said this simply is not possible.

Comment: I noticed one thing. From my Mac, I can ping pgmaster.docker-compose_cluster where pgmaster is the container name and docker-compose_cluster is the network name. The hostname is resolved with IP 54.72.52.58 that I never defined. Where it come from?

Comment: docker compose creates a subnet and generates an ip for each services. thats why (to me) it doesnt seem necessary to have that `networks` block in your docker-compose. it makes things way more complicated.